# Upload image from Android app through php move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, android, image, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload image file from my android app to a server. This is my php file that is processing incoming images from my website and iOS app to be used in `move_uploaded_file` function:

```
<?php include '../../../init.php';

  $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

  $image_temp   = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $image_name   = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $image_ext    = strtolower(end(explode('.', $image_name)));

  upload_page_image($image_temp, $image_ext, $post_id);
```

Now, in android I came up to the point when I have Base64 encoded string:

```
  params.put("image",imageToString(bitmap));
```

Then, I bring this to my PHP file like this:

```
  <$php
  .... 
  $image = base64_decode(_POST['image']);
  ...
```

But now, how do I brake it in to `$_FILES['image']['temp_name']` and `$_FILES['image']['name']`? All the other examples I went through are using `file_put_contents`. I need it to be `move_uploaded_files`.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me [enter link description here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/)

Answer (score 0):

You must submit image using **Multipart Form Data** for use **move_uploaded_files** in php

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was the most difficult stuff I ever went through. The problem is that when I use php function `file_put_contents()`, it first makes everything easy on android app side, just convert bitmap to Base64 and pass it to php file. But... **one very important thing got lost** in this process.... it's that `$exif['Orientation']` when using `exif_read_data`. This parameter is not there any more.

Now, when going back to android app and trying to get image orientation before sending the file to php, the standard function such as below:

```
ExifInterface exifReader = new ExifInterface(mFilePath);
exifReader.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
```

.. or similar **doesn't work. It always returns 0. ALWAYS**

Solution came from using Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide library and get current image orientation using:

```
InputStream is = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(originalUri);
int orientation = new ImageHeaderParser(is).getOrientation();
```

Once you get orientation, you pass image as Base64 and orientation number and then process upload and do orientation change and so on.